# Unity: How to acces Android stereo back camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-camera, stereo-3d

I want to get frames from back cameras at the same time (to compute the disparity map) on an Android smartphone, is there a way to do it?

I tried to get the list of a smartphone with 2 rear cameras and a front camera using ''`WebCamTexture.devices`" and it displays only two cameras: a back and a front camera. I then tried to display "`WebCamDevice.depthCameraName`" and I got nothing.

I know that there is a Depth API that provide depth image but I don't want to use it since it's based on a SLAM algorithm.

I appreciate your help, I'm still newbie in Unity.

Comment: Unity does not expose the physical camera streams, only the combined logical stream. If you wish, you have to write native Android code that will work directly with **camera2** API.